# Approaching TCP programming with .NET 4.0x

Tags: .net, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I need to talk to a Samsung cash register SPS 500 that understands custom TCP commands.

I've never done this before and am wondering where to get started using .NET 4.x, are there **3rd party tools** like SocketWrench 7.2 (which cost money) or is it better to use the **built-in .NET APIs**.

Basically I have to built a command with a numebr of bits and bytes (a header, apyload and a CRC) send this to the register (which has an IP address) and expect something back (an ACK, or message or whatever).

What I get back again has to be read and evaluated.

**Questions:
1. How would I begin, using the specifications given to me, usign .NET 4?
2. How would I best debug what is being sent on the wire? Wireshark?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Questions: 1. How would I begin, using the specifications given to me, usign .NET 4? 2. How would I best debug what is being sent on the wire? Wireshark?

I would begin by hoping the vendor (Samsung in this case) provides a mock (for example a debug console) that responds to valid and invalid commands without having to connect to it using TCP. Then you can test your commands and debug it, without having to doubt your socket programming capabilities.

Now when the "dry" one is functional, you connect it to a TCP one, since sockets really just send the bytes you feed it. So this isn't as much about sockets as it is about command building and interpretation.

But you could indeed look at (for example) the [`TcpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) and [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html).

Comment: thanks sir! Samsung or better yet the distributor does not and will not help beyond giving me lousy specs. So no help from that end. I only have a maschine where the register is hooked up and working.